# Enabling HipHop syntax for PHP tests in TravisCI

Tags: php, automated-tests, travis-ci

How can I enable HipHop syntax for PHP sources when running tests with TravisCI?

I had the error below:

```
Fatal error: Syntax only allowed in Hack files (<?hh) 
or with -v Eval.EnableHipHopSyntax=true in 
/home/travis/build/Corviz/framework/src/String/StringUtils.php 
on line 20
```

The project itself is being developed to run primarily with php 7+, so the `<?hh` is not an option. I could not find anything related until now.

This is my configuration file: https://github.com/Corviz/framework/blob/master/.travis.yml

Comment: The solution is in the error message

Comment: @CharlotteDunois `... or with -v Eval.EnableHipHopSyntax=true ...` noticed that. I just want to know what configuration I need to put in `.travis.yml` to accomplish it. That is the question btw...